# mvc 4 error Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

### The ViewData item that has the key 'WorkStations' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

This is the error im getting, I am getting the value that the dropbox is sending, but when it try to add it to the data it just crashes and im getting the error that i wrote abow.

This is my model

```
namespace MvCfirstproject.Models
{
    [Table("WorkHoursModels")]
    public class WorkhoursModels
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string Stop { get; set; }
        public string command { get; set; }
        public string Users { get; set; }
        public string WorkStations { get; set; }
       

    }
    [Table("WorkStations")]
    public class WorkHoursStation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string WorkStations { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Workstations { get; set; }
    }


    public class WorkhourDB : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<WorkhoursModels> WorkHours { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkHoursStation> WorkStation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.WorkStations = new SelectList(db.WorkStation, "WorkStations", "Workstations");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Default1/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(WorkhoursModels workhoursmodels)
    {
        if (workhoursmodels.command == "Users")
        {
            db.WorkHours.Add(workhoursmodels);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And this is my view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Users)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users)
        </div>
     
     <div>
       @Html.DropDownList("WorkStations", String.Empty)
    </div>
              <p>
             <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.command)" value="User"/>

        </p>

 }
```

Comment: Just tell me if the question is badly written, and i try to re-phrase myself, in a more understanding way.

Comment: I think save operation works fine. Have you checked your database ?

Comment: Yes, nothing is saved..

Answer (score 0):

You need to update dropdown list to

```
   @Html.DropDownList(@ViewBag.Name.WorkStations, String.Empty)
```

**Updated:**

```
   @Html.DropDownList("WorkStations", (SelectList)ViewBag.WorkStations)
```

Comment: try changing it to 

   @Html.DropDownList(ViewBag.WorkStations, String.Empty)

Comment: Tried doing that, i'll get this error 

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvCfirstproject.Models.WorkhoursModels>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Try - @Html.DropDownList("WorkStations",(SelectList)ViewBag.WorkStations)

Comment: Still getting that error..

The ViewData item that has the key 'WorkStations' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it does work.

My Assignment.cs Model (for a Group selection list using a Groups.cs Model)

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    //required for SelectListItem
```

and

```
   public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
```

In my Controller

```
//adds framework for populating dropdown list
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

In my View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group.GName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("GroupID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupID)
    </div>
</div>
```